# How can I use jQuery to highlight ONLY the selected thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, thumbnails

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]
Here's a snippet of the html:

```
<section id="obstacles">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="box inactive topBox" id="theTank">
            <img src="http://fpoimg.com/150x150">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="large-3 columns end">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="box inactive topBox rightBox" id="sundaeSlide">
            <img src="http://fpoimg.com/150x150">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-3 columns">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="box inactive" id="hamster">
            <img src="http://fpoimg.com/150x150">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="large-3 columns end">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="box inactive rightBox" id="downTheHatch">
            <img src="http://fpoimg.com/150x150">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns large-offset-6">
        <a href="#"><img id="smallSlime" src="/assets/otherAssets/smallSlime.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns large-offset-6">
        <a href="#">
          <hgroup>
            <h2>Down the Hatch</h2>
            <h3>6ft Slide Covered in Gunk!</h3>
          </hgroup>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </section>
```

And here's the jQuery I'm using to change the large picture that shows up on the right:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#theTank").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='/assets/obstacles/the-tank.png' />");
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    })

    $("#sundaeSlide").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='/assets/obstacles/sundae-slide.png' />");
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    })

    $("#hamster").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='/assets/obstacles/hamster-wheel.png' />");
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    })

    $("#downTheHatch").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='/assets/obstacles/down-the-hatch.png' />");
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    })

    $("#pickIt").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='/assets/obstacles/pick-it.png' />");
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    })

    $("#theWringer").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='/assets/obstacles/the-wringer.png' />");
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    })
})
```

Right now, when I click on the thumbnail image on the left, the background turns yellow and the correct large image displays on the right. However, when I click another image, the highlighted image remains highlighted. I am sure there is an easy fix to this, I'm just not confident of how to traverse the DOM to do what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: instead of all that click event for every img .. use click event for all of that and then use $(this) to get the src of img and apply it to the div in the right

Comment: Can you give me an example? I do think it's too much code and figured there was a simpler way.

Comment: sure i posted example code in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$(".active").toggleClass("active inactive");
```

Add this as the first line in your click functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function() {
    var LMenuItems = $("a > .box");
    var RMenuItem = $(".largeObstacles");

    LMenuItems.foreach(function(MenuItem) {
        MenuItem.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            RMenuItem.html(MenuItem.childNodes[1]);

            // Combined with Bill Read's answer -> Box class containing active class
            $(".box > .active").toggleClass("active inactive");
        }
    });
}());
```

This method allows you to select all the menu items you have on the left menu by creating an array. Using `.foreach` allows you to iterate through the array and bind the click event to each menu object you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#theTank, #anotherimg").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='"+imgsrc+"' />");
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mention. Your code makes it difficult because you are using individual event listeners for each element.

A good way to solve this would be to make your code more universal.

**Adjusting for my lack of attention in seeing that the image source are different for small/large images.**

First make you dom elements share a universal selector (.small-image)
And use a data-attribute on you element containing the large image src.
Note I used the same image for both just to make examples easier. Each data-imgsrc should have its respective image.

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="box inactive small-image" id="hamster" data-imgsrc="/assets/obstacles/the-tank.png">
      <img src="http://fpoimg.com/150x150">
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns end">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="box inactive rightBox small-image" id="downTheHatch" data-imgsrc="/assets/obstacles/the-tank.png">
      <img src="http://fpoimg.com/150x150">
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then with your javascript we can simple pull the `data-imgsrc` attribute from out clicked element and set it to the large container.

```
$('.small-image').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // remove any currently active small-images
    $('.small-image.active').removeClass('active');
    // make clicked active
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // Get the image src from the clicked elements data-imgsrc attribute
    // and inject into large container
    var imgText = '<img src="{img-src}" />';
    var imgSrc = $(this).data('imgsrc');
    $('.largeObstacles').html(imgText.replace('{img-src}', imgSrc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam. For some reason this isn't working for me. I"m a little confused on how the image source is working. The thumbnail image and larger image are completely separate files.

Comment: Yeah I had overlooked that little (but very important detail). Adjusted the code above to work correctly. If you have never worked with data attributes [here is some good reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best solution I've found:

```
("#obstacles .small-image").on('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selector = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
        var image = $(this).find('img').attr('data-attr-putItOver');
        $(".small-image.active").removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $(selector).addClass('active');
        $('.largeObstacles').html("<img src='"+image+"' />");
    });
```